# gulp-rev-replace on HTML files in subfolders

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rev

I'm wondering how to get gulp-rev-replace to replace file references with the same hash across HTML files in subfolders. Considering the following file structure

- index.html
- subfolder

  - index.html
- scripts

  - main.js
- styles

  - main.scss

And the following html statements:

index.html:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

subfolder/index.html:

```
<!-- build:css ../styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And the following in my Gulpfile

```
gulp.task('html', ['styles'], () => {
  const assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']});

  return gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify()))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.minifyCss({compatibility: '*'})))
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml({conditionals: true, loose: true})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The style link block in `index.html` will get replacced with the correct minified and hashed stylesheet reference. The same block in `subfolder/index.html` will instead get an entirely different hashed stylesheet reference. It does, however, get the path of the stylesheet correct.

Am I setting up my Gulpfile incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of this [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350835/gulp-useref-is-throwing-error-path-must-be-a-string). I ended up setting the style references in each HTML file to the root of the app directory and supplying 3 directories to search:

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp,app,.}) /styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Which matches the three directories supplied to gulp-useref

```
const assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']});
```